# Turn off Android Instant Run via gradle property?

Tags: android, gradle, android-instant-run

I know that instant run may be turned off via the Settings dialog, but I'd like to be able to turn it off via a property from within a gradle build script itself.  So that regardless of which instance of Android Studio loads this project it will never build with instant run enabled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Android Instant is a new feature in build tools 2.1.0,so you can decrease ths vesion to 2.0.0.
**example in build script**:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
}
```

You will also need to change your project settings to use gradle version between `2.10 - 2.13` [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

Comment: What if I want to use the latest gradle and disable Instant Run for just one project?

Comment: That's not a solution. What if I'm on gradle 3.5? OP is asking for a specific gradle property to set.